# JMeter not picking right dynamic file name for CSV data set config

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jsr223

In first Thread Group,JSR223 sampler creates a new file in format Filename_HHMM, where as HHMM are current hour & minute in docs folder.The script returns Filename_hhmm and other object as form of JSON.
In second Thread Group, JSR223 sampler is used to extract the filename and other object from response and store as Filename_HHMM as Props "NewFile" and other object with other prop name.
A CSV config data set is added after JSR223 in 2nd TG, the file name is given as c://users//docs//${__P(NewFile)},hoping the csv config file will use the data from new file created for every min and further HTTP samplers are processed from the test data from newfile.
Test duration is 30min. So 30 NewFile files will be generated with HHMM and csv config file needs to pick the file for the currenth hour and minute and execute the test.

We noticed that first TG,JSR223 sampler creates correct file with HHMM and NewFile is also stored with right filename.
But the Filename in CSV data config, is taking old minute file instead of the NewFile with current hh & mm.

Let's say, If I start test at 10:30AM, Fileaname_1030 is created in JSR223 TG1 and stored in docs folder.  JSR223 TG2 stores Fileaname_1030 as NewFile. So the Csv filename should be c://users//Fileaname_1030 but in log the csv filename will be c://users//Fileaname_1025 or some old time.

Comment: Did you check the option `Run Thread Groups consecutively` in Test Plan? And where did you set property `NewFile`?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [JMeter Test Elements Execution Order](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder)

> 0. Configuration elements
> 1. Pre-Processors
> 2. Timers
> 3. Sampler
> 4. Post-Processors (unless SampleResult is null)
> 5. Assertions (unless SampleResult is null)
> 6. Listeners (unless SampleResult is null)

Being a "Configuration Element" CSV Data Set Config is executed **before** any Sampler. Moreover the filename is being set during initialization and only once

If you want to use dynamic file names - consider going for the [__CSVRead()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) function instead

Another possible option is updating one CSV file instead of creating a new one.

Also given you generate some JSON in Groovy you can simply get rid of this "file" step and directly set the HTTP Request sampler payload using [`sampler` shorthand](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes) from the [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor).